# Kafka connect getting fail to submit task

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I am trying to run Kafka connect on k8s cluster, problem i am facing is during submitting the connector. I am running 4 task with different topics and wanted to store data to S3.

I created 4 different connector and when i am trying to submit it I found sometimes the connector runs fine but most of the time the connector get started but no task were running even though the connector shows running.
When i looked into the error logs i found below error

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Internal request missing required signature
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:162)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:116)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:80)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.HerderRequestHandler.completeOrForwardRequest(HerderRequestHandler.java:112)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.HerderRequestHandler.completeOrForwardRequest(HerderRequestHandler.java:127)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.HerderRequestHandler.completeOrForwardRequest(HerderRequestHandler.java:137)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.InternalClusterResource.putTaskConfigs(InternalClusterResource.java:85)
 at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:256)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:273)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:181)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-02-27 21:16:32,648] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2024:21:16:32 +0000] "POST /connectors/SessionizerOutS3SinkConnector-H/tasks HTTP/1.1" 400 74 "-" "kafka-connect" 12 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2024-02-27 21:16:32,648] ERROR Error forwarding REST request (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Internal request missing required signature
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:162)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:116)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$publishConnectorTaskConfigs$42(DistributedHerder.java:2054)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-02-27 21:16:32,650] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-master-group] Request to leader to reconfigure connector tasks failed (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Internal request missing required signature
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:162)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:116)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$publishConnectorTaskConfigs$42(DistributedHerder.java:2054)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-02-27 21:16:32,650] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafka-connect-master-group] Failed to reconfigure connector's tasks (SessionizerOutS3SinkConnector-H), retrying after backoff. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Internal request missing required signature
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:162)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:116)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$publishConnectorTaskConfigs$42(DistributedHerder.java:2054)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The topic which i am trying to read has 50 partitions and tried with different number of task in connector but facing same issue.

[image: Kafka-Connect-UI]

My Kafka-connect version is 7.5.1.

I tried with multiple restart with the cluster but no luck, tried with different param values thought may be some memory issue but i am wrong.

Can some one please help me here?

Thanks

Comment: `Internal request missing required signature` typically indicates an issue related to authentication or authorization in Kafka Connect. Doublecheck you configurations, check the logs `connect-worker.log` . Also you can cry update it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rooted in the security configuration of the Kafka Connect cluster's REST API.
For each worker in the `Kafka Connect` cluster do the following:

1. check the property `connect.protocol` in your worker configuration file. If it is there then set the value of this property to `sessioned`. OR simply remove this property from the worker configuration file.
2. Restart the worker.

This will properly configure the request verification with the default key verification algorithm for communication between processes on workers and the REST API Endpoint.

[Further reference: Apache Forum Discussion on securing the REST Endpoints](https://lists.apache.org/thread/07hvsff0g9vc18ogo8j2gk7bsnz35ncj)